# How to write to a specific line of a file?

Tags: python, file

Let's say I have a text file

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

I read through it and decide to change Line 2 to Line Two. Can I do that elegantly in Python without simply rewriting the file with the changes? I tried with file.seek() but I didn't really get anywhere with it nor I understand what it does exactly.

Comment: "Can I do that elegantly in Python without simply rewriting the file with the changes?" - you can't do this in any *mainstream* programming language or operating system without rewriting the file. It's simply not how stream-based file IO works. If you want to work on records (such as "lines of text"), you need a database of some sort. `file.seek()` is only useful to **overwrite** bytes in the middle of a file.

Comment: So what file.seek(offset) does is, it sets the current position of the file as of "start writing at the offset byte"?

Comment: That's pretty much it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A file is a sequence of bytes. If you want to change something in the middle that requires more or fewer bytes to express, the rest of the file needs to resize.

Because a file is a *physical* sequence of bytes on a storage medium, that means you need to rewrite the entire *rest* of the file. In other words, you need to move over everything following `line 2`.

In practice, that means rewriting the file, as that is much easier to achieve.

Comment: Also, it's important to understand that hard drives work with a constant size sectors (standard are 512 bytes) so an entire sector on the hard drive will be re-written no matter what you do.

Comment: The OS takes care of those details; from the programming-language POV you still need to shift everything following changed line up or down depending on whether you added or removed bytes.

Comment: If the file is *very* big and you are doing modifications regularly, you could also want to start writing the modification to the end of the file and once there are enough modifications rewrite the whole file. This means you don't have to rewrite the whole file every time.

Answer (score 2):

You want the power of in-place editing, which the `fileinput` module offers:

inplace-edit.py:

```
import sys
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input(sys.argv[1], inplace=1):
    line = line.rstrip() # Remove the new line
    if line == 'Line 2':
        line = 'Line two'
    print line
```

data.txt:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

To run it:

```
python inplace-edit.py data.txt
```

The resulting data.txt:

```
Line 1
Line two
Line 3
```